# Periodically check to see if all threads have completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, system.timers.timer

I have an multithreaded application and I want to be able to use a timer to periodically check to see if all threads have finished before starting a new one, ie:

```
var checkStatusTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(CheckThreads), null, 10000, 10000);
```

This is as far as I've come. What would need to go in the CheckThreads Method to check to see if they're done? I was thinking of something along the lines of a function that checks them like:

```
                foreach (Thread thread in Threads)
            {
                Thread t = thread;
                if (t.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
                    return false;
            }
```

Am I on the right track? is this the correct way to go about this?  Or should I use a System.Timers.Timer instead? Also, the function form within I want to do this periodic check is static. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you add the tag [tag:C#] or whatever this is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task` instead of `Thread`. Then, you can create a combined task:

```
Task[] tasks = ...; //You provide this
Task combined = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Now you can check for completion: `combined.IsCompleted`. You can also `Wait` and `await` that task.

`Thread` is a legacy API that is rarely a good idea to use.

Comment: The application is running in .NET 3.5 which I believe doesn't support Tasks.

Comment: @user609926 Use this nuget package to introduce Task to .net 3.5: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/

Answer (score 0):

@usr's task-based approach is best, but if you must rely on threads, then I suggest that as each thread is completes it invokes a method that removes the thread from your `Threads` collection. Then all you have to do in your timer callback is to check the count of the collection. Relying on ThreadState [is not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010174/150058).