# How to find the current state of a thread in the scheduler strucure in windows

Tags: windows, multithreading

I want to know the current state(SUSPENDED/READY/RUNNING/WAITING state ) of a thread which has been created by CreateThread() api.

How can I find it out?

My developement environment is Visual studio 2008 Expresss edition

also language is C/C++

/renjith g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been previously answered :-

[Check if a Win32 thread is running or in a suspended state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006691/how-to-check-if-a-win32-thread-is-running-or-in-suspended-state/1007295#1007295)

APIs that provide this information are not provided because the information they return is stale before they return. 
If you want to know if a thread is suspended - call SuspendThread. Now you know (a) the thread has a suspend count of at least 1, and, as SuspendThread returns the 'previous' suspend count, you can know that, at some point during the call to SuspendThread, the suspend count *was* 0, or some number.
The same logic holds for testing if a thread is "stuck" in WaitForXObject(s) :- until you've stopped the thread, you can't know the answer to that question safely.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this [Thread Status Monitor](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/thread-status-monitor/index.html) (free) useful for viewing the state of threads in your app.