# getting a thread state in c++/windows

Tags: c++, thread-state

There must be a function that gets the current status of a thread in the system because
there is this application: http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/thread-status-monitor/index.html

It must be using some sort of API function or something...
How can I get a thread state myself in C++/Windows?
thanks :)

(this is my last question for today. I promise :))

Comment: Out of interest I downloaded the thread state app (it's free) to try it out. It does not display any process, and therefore thread, information in XP so I can only assume it's using API calls only available in Vista/Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following examples to get the running processes and, when you have a process ID, the threads.

[Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Traversing the Thread List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686852(v=vs.85).aspx)

**EDIT:** After getting the handle to the thread(s) you are interested in you can call `GetExitCodeThread` but that will only tell you if the thread is `STILL_ACTIVE` until it ends, when you can find the exit code.

While searching for the additional information for your comment I also came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006691/how-to-check-if-a-win32-thread-is-running-or-in-suspended-state) on SO which might be of interest to you.

Comment: @ldov: Added some more info to my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

That's done via Toolhelp library, check information at MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686780%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You get the most bang out of WMI, [Win32_Thread class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The linked article has a link to the C++ code you need.  Experiment with the WMI Code Creator tool.

Comment: I know, it sucks that you can do this in a scripting language with so little code. But the query itself is the same in any language.  Use the tool to verify that your C++ code works properly.