# How can I know that threads of my application are working or hovered?

Tags: c++, winapi, process, mfc

I need to write application that collect information about processes in windows. I can read number of threads and thread's id, memory that used by process. But i dont know how i can check working or not working threads in process. I'm using VS2010 and C++ with MFC. How can i do this?

Comment: Are you looking to see "how much CPU time each thread within my process is using"? Or see "is my thread doing what I expect it to do?", or perhaps "Is my thread blocked waiting for some event?"

Comment: Have you checked these links ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608838/getting-a-thread-state-in-c-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006691/check-if-a-win32-thread-is-running-or-in-a-suspended-state

Comment: What do you mean by "hovered"?