# Get ThreadState of suspended thread

Tags: c, winapi

For a simple sampling profiler I'm suspending a target thread, get its current stacktrace, then continue it.
Now I would like to highlight a sample differently if the thread was in a waiting state.

So I want to know if the thread was blocking (waiting via WaitForSingleObject, pausing via Sleep, ...) at the time it was suspended.

I can get this information via [NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation), but that gets much more than needed, the information of each thread of each process.

Also I saw [Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/perfctrs/using-the-registry-functions-to-consume-counter-data), but I'm not sure if it's possible with this API, if I only have the thread ID/handle.

UPDATE:
IInspectable gave me a hint with [Wait Chain Traversal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/wait-chain-traversal), while it seemed a good fit, it gives back the status `ObjectStatus==WctStatusBlocked` for all suspended threads, which isn't unreasonable, but doesn't work for my problem. It is also very slow, I assume because it collects the data for the whole chain, while I only care for the first element.

Comment: *"but that gets much more than needed"* - Is that a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a Win32 thread is running or in a suspended state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006691/check-if-a-win32-thread-is-running-or-in-a-suspended-state)

Comment: Do you mean suspended or merely blocked?  Oh, you want to know if it was blocked before you suspended it...

Comment: @mnistic: Definitely not a duplicate.  OP knows the thread is suspended, because he suspended it.

Comment: [Wait Chain Traversal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/wait-chain-traversal) may get you that information.

Comment: @Broman Yes, this is done periodically, so it would slow down the process a lot.

Comment: @IInspectable Sadly, `GetThreadWaitChain` always says a thread has `ObjectStatus==WctStatusBlocked` if it is suspended, otherwise this would have been perfect.

Comment: Hmm, a sampling profiler needs to walk the stack.  A stack that has a wait function on it just isn't very special, there are only a small subset of native functions.  Do this at display-time instead of sampling-time, human eyes are not that fast.

Comment: @HansPassant That was actually my first idea as well, but this isn't always reliable. For example when doing a `_getch()` I have `ZwRequestWaitReplyPort` in the top level for 64bit, but on 32bit it's `DuplicateConsoleHandle` for some reason. But maybe that still is the best solution anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly what I wanted, [QueryThreadCycleTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-querythreadcycletime) is close enough.

So each time the thread is suspended, `QueryThreadCycleTime` is called, which returns the number of CPU clock cycles used by this thread up to this point.
If the difference to the previous call is below a certain limit, the current sample is then considered as waiting.

It's not perfect, the first sample taken while the thread entered a waiting state is not detected as waiting, and the limit might not work for all CPUs the same.